# text widget keeps centering without centre widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

[image link since i'm not allowed to post images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8AYw.png)

I'm trying to create an app but the two texts 'hello and mr '' are in the center even when I've not added the center widget and why do they have that amount of space between them. the app title had a massive bottom padding that i had to remove it.' the app sample is in the image above.
I just want the two to stack above each other in the top left corner, and the space between them to reduce, Here's my code:

```
    Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Hello,',
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme.headline4
                .apply( color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          Text(
            "Mr. Udeinya",
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headline4
                .apply(color: Colors.deepOrange, fontWeightDelta: 2),
          ),

          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Wallet Balance :',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),

                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

and the image

[image link since i'm not allowed to post images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8AYw.png)

Comment: Hello. Your description of the issue is very difficult to understand. Please take a look at the question guidelines to make to make improvements: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you attempted to use the `MainAxisAlignment` and `CrossAxisAlignment` properties of the Column Widget?

Comment: Have you tried using the `RichText` Widget instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your problem would be to change the crossAxisAlignment property of your column to CrossAxisAlignment.start

I would also recommend, if you intend to group them together, to put your two text widgets together in a column themselves.

```
Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Hello,',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline4
                    .apply(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
              Text(
                "Mr. Udeinya",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline4
                    .apply(color: Colors.deepOrange, fontWeightDelta: 2),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Wallet Balance :',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Something like This ? Hope that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use text align property of Text widget you can find more in the link. [Text widget documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)

Example:

```
 Text("data,",textAlign: TextAlign.left,)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not giving a crossAxisAlignment to the top-most column, so by default, it is centred.Add this to the top-most Column

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Comment: ah thank you for your help. would this also fix the space between them